# How to set version numbers and package file names via dpkg-buildpackge for automated builds on a build server?

Tags: dpkg, packaging

Our build server builds ubuntu packages (*.deb) via `dpkg-buildpackage`. The server checks out the source code via git and runs the build via `make <target>`. The source directory contains the `debian/` subdirectory where the dpkg configuration files are.

I would like to add the internal build counter number to the current package version and further set the package file name but `dpkg-buildpackage` does not let me control how the resulting `package_version_arch.deb` looks like. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [git-buildpackage](http://honk.sigxcpu.org/projects/git-buildpackage/manual-html/gbp.releases.html#GBP.RELEASE.NUMBERS):

> ## Customizing snapshot numbers
>
> If the auto incrementing of the snapshot number doesn't suite you needs you can give any python expression that evaluates to a positive integer to calculate the new snapshot number:
>
> ```
> gbp dch -S -a --snapshot-number=1  
> gbp dch -S -a --snapshot-number='snapshot + 2'
> gbp dch -S -a --snapshot-number='os.popen("git-log --pretty=oneline | wc -l").readlines()[0]'
> gbp dch -S -a --snapshot-number=`git-log --pretty=oneline debian/0.3.3 | wc -l`
> ```
>
> You can also add the snapshot-number calculation to `gbp.conf`:
>
> ```
> [DEFAULT]
> snapshot-number = os.popen("git-log --pretty=oneline | wc -l").readlines()[0]
> ```

Comment: `dch` alone does neither accept `-S` nor `--snapshot-number`.

Comment: @Stefan why should it, when that is an option provided by `git-buildpackage`? Think of `dch` in this case as a command to `gbp`, like commit, and not as executable passed on to `dch` as an argument. See the man page: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/gbp-dch.1.html

Comment: I understand. Still I do not want to use `git-buildpackage` but `dpkg-buildpackage` alone as `git-buildpackage` again has certain requirements for project/directory layout.

Comment: @Stefan, does setting a version manually using the `--newversion` option of `dch` work?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the version number in the control file, sampkg/DEBIAN/control

The control file is the core of the Debian package; it contains all relevant metadata. Things such as package name, version, supported architectures, and dependencies are all included in this file.

```
Package: sampkg
Architecture: all
Essential: no
Section: web
Priority: optional
Depends: python (>=2.3)
Maintainer: Swaminathan Mathivanan
Description: Sample package.
```

And the final pkg name will be sampkg_**1.0.0**_all.deb

Comment: I know, but I need to do it in an automated way. For instance, the Version in the control file could be `1.2.3ubuntu3~ppa3` and I want to add my build number as well => `1.2.3ubuntu3~ppa3-<buildnumber>`

Comment: For that you need to keep one more tmp control file for adding the <buildNumber> to the deb package. once the build number is ready and you can sed/replace the build number to tmp control file and save it to the original control file. like Version: 1.0.0.$$BUILD$$

Comment: How can I specify a custom control file to `dpkg-buildpackage`?